# Recover last interactive rebase TODO after abort?

Tags: git

Let's say I'm doing an interactive rebase of a branch containing around 20 commits. In the TODO file, I squash, reword, and reorder commits. All together it's a lot of work to setup this rebase because there is a bunch to do.

Over half way through the rebase, I bork something. I cancel the rebase by doing `git rebase --abort`. I start the rebase again to do it all over, because I messed up a single commit along the way (maybe I resolved a conflict poorly and didn't realize it until later through the rebase process).

Now I have to edit the TODO all over again. Does Git not remember the last TODO file I configured? Can it not remember the commit messages I reworded?

Perhaps a more simple question is, instead of aborting a whole rebase just to fix a simple mistake, is there perhaps a way to just rewind the interactive rebase back a few steps and restart from that point?

Comment: Did you ever bother proposing / reporting this to the git project? I regularly encounter the exact issue you explained here for non-trivial commit (commonly swapping two commits which should not be swapped), and there seems to still be no way to restore a previously aborted rebase built in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly after all this time, I never found a good built-in solution for this. The technique I use today is quite simple actually.

After setting up the rebase how you want, before saving and closing the file, copy & paste the whole contents to another temp notepad window.

If you need to completely abort the rebase and try it again later, just copy & paste the contents back from the temp window. Works for me!

Comment: UPDATE: sorry, I just noticed that the `~` file is a backup from texteditor, it's not 100% identical, it's a version 1-save-before-the-final, eh. However, the cleaned up `.backup` seems usable.

Answer (score 4):

For each successful step in the rebase a new commit will be created, and recorded in the reflog. So you could leverage that to essentially start over at the last successful point with a new rebase.

**Example:**

```bash
git rebase --abort # Oops! I notice I messed up during rebase
git reflog         # find the last "good" rebase hash created

git rebase -i --onto <last-good-hash> \
<branchname>~<number of commits that were not replayed>
```

This is a rather clunky approach but considering a long/difficult rebase, it might be worth it. This essentially recreates the TODO beginning at the point that you aborted.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just cherry pick a range onto new branch without interactive rebasing?

Comment: @mlt That would be an option for rebasing onto another branch, but if the rebase is to cleanup the commit history then I think I would use this approach. One other thing is that even if you create a new branch you still might encounter conflicts during the cherry-pick. I might be misunderstanding your comment.

Comment: You can combine steps 3-5 by using `rebase --onto`. Use the reflog to find the last "good" rebase hash created. Then: `git rebase -i --onto <last-good-hash> <branchname>~<number of commits that were not replayed>`. This essentially recreates the TODO that you aborted. Ex: `git rebase -i --onto 1234567 myBranch~5`. Replays the last 5 commits on my branch onto 1234567 which is the hypothetical point where I left off.

Comment: Also: you'll still have to edit the todo file again. This allows you to avoid redoing the commits which you've already rebased, but I'm not familiar with a way to have git resume from a previous todo file.

Answer (score 1):

For such a complex and long rebase, you could try **[git-imerge](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge)**, which handles [*incremental* merge and rebase](http://softwareswirl.blogspot.fr/2013/05/git-imerge-practical-introduction.html) for git.

That way, "borking" at any point means that you can stop, fix, and resume your rebase session.

### Note

Aborting a rebase effectively deletes the `.git/rebase-merge` folder [which contains](http://makandracards.com/makandra/13011-git-in-an-interactive-rebase-find-out-which-commit-you-are-currently-working-on-until-version-1-7-9-5)

- Commit hash that you are currently applying

  > ```
  > cat .git/rebase-merge/stopped-sha
  > ```
  >
  > Useful if you want to inspect the original commit for its changes, for example like:
  >
  > ```
  > git show `cat .git/rebase-merge/stopped-sha`
  > ```
- Current commit's message

  > ```
  > cat .git/rebase-merge/message
  > ```
  >
  > In case you forgot what the changes are supposed to do.
- **Remaining rebase task list**

  > ```
  > cat .git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo
  > ```
  >
  > All commits that will be applied after the current one (and their "strategy", e.g. pick, squash, …)
- Hash of the target commit/branch that your (entire) rebase is applied to

  > ```
  > cat .git/rebase-merge/onto
  > ```
  >
  > Handy when you want to look at that branch's state of the file.

Comment: Based on the responses I'm getting it seems like a good feature to implement for git-rebase. Native support to "remember" the last rebase operation would be nice.