# Can I get the todo-list from a concluded git rebase -i?

Tags: git

Say that I've done a large cleanup of my commit history with `git rebase --interactive`.
I've gone through every commit and marked it either as squash / pick / delete and reordered commits to make them more focused. I then realize that I've made a mistake and would like to change some things, is it possible to get the todo-list with all of the changes I made back after I have concluded the rebase?

Comment: If I understand you, then you have to inspect the reflog to get the original branch last commit before the rebase started, and run `git rebase -i <ORIGINAL_BASE_COMMIT_ID> <ORIGINAL_COMMIT_ID>` in order to get the original rebase sequence. It must produce the same sequence. If it's fine and appears the same, then you could reset your branch to the ORIGINAL_COMMIT_ID and run the rebase again. I often do similar things, but don't use reflog since I "save" the work in my exclusive branches on remote. And I also try to make as few changes in a single rebase session as possible before I "save" it.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me (or maybe I you), I want to get the sequence that contains the changes I made to it, not the sequence I started with.

Comment: I misunderstood you. As far as I know, once the rebase is finished, the TODO sequence from `.git/git-rebase-merge` or `.git/git-rebase-apply` is gone. But as far as I can see, reflog seems to be the source to reconstruct the original TODO sequence from. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215597/recover-last-interactive-rebase-todo-after-abort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fluffy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65328591/can-i-get-the-todo-list-from-a-concluded-git-rebase-i#comment115496512_65328591) is entirely correct: once the rebase is finished, Git deletes the entire temporary directory in which the various chunks of rebase information were stored, including the rebase-to-do file.  By repeating the rebase (via information stored in reflogs) you can have Git construct an all-new rebase-to-do file, but it won't have any edits you made to it.

The only solution here is to save the instructions somewhere else, in addition to in the file that Git constructed.  You'll have to do this semi-manually, but perhaps you can teach your editor to do this automatically by recognizing the format of a git rebase to-do file name and saving it not only back in the original name, but also somewhere else.

(My own method for handling particularly complex rebases is not to use `git rebase` directly.  I make a new branch, and then either use rebase on it if that seems like the way to go, or do my own individual cherry-picks and other operations if that seems like the way to go.  Different situations tend to call for different tools.)